# Iphone SDK Help me for a request to show only one category from data plist !

Tags: iphone, database, cocoa-touch, plist

I look for a friends who can help me for long time !
I'm beginner and I try to understand... HOW I can make a request to show all data (from plist) in SAME category (NOT ALL !) for exemple : show only the movie have : genre = Action

Please help me ...
Thanks a lot !
Excuse my bad english !

Is it in this code I must make it or an other ???

- (id)initWithLibraryName:(NSString *)libraryName {
  if (self = [super init]) {
      libraryPlist = libraryName;
      libraryContent = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
     pathForResource:libraryPlist ofType:@"plist"]];

you can download the source for help me on : http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/MyDVDLibrary03.zip PLEASE SAY ME HOW I CAN DO IT !

I will want to know the exact CODE LINE and WHERE I must write it !
For see a the list of product are in Action.

THANKS VERY VERY MUCH

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to download the sample project and go through the code for you, but you want to do is use NSArray's filteredArrayWithPredicate method to filter the objects in `libraryContent`. [This is a pretty decent tutorial](http://www.drobnik.com/touch/2010/03/filtering-fun-with-predicates/) for using predicates.

Comment: You are very cool ! Thanks so much to help me to understand how to use it ! I try to understand but few things block me ... have you got a mail ?